# Unreachable member in derived class in template class

Tags: c++, templates

Here is the code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Outer {
  struct InnerBase {
    int n;
    InnerBase() : n(42) { }
  };
  struct InnerChild : InnerBase {
    int getN() { return n; }
  };
};
```

And here is the problem:

```
In member function 'int Outer<T>::InnerChild::getN()':
error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
```

If the `Outer` is not a template, everything works fine. How so? How to fix it in the template?

Comment: @KerrekSB: It works, should be an answer. But it is still unclear to me what is the problem with templates here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`InnerBase` is not a free-standing type, but actually a dependent class, since it is really `Outer<T>::InnerBase`. Thus `InnerChild` doesn't know from whom exactly it is inheriting (think of specializations*!), and thus it cannot know that `n` is actually a name.

To assert that `n` is indeed a name of a class member, say `this->n` or `InnerBase::n`, or add a declaration `using InnerBase::n;` at some point in `InnerChild`.

<sub>*) e.g. `template <> struct Outer<int>::InnerBase { typedef int n; };`</sub>

Comment: +1 just because i happened to read it and it seems to be correct and to the point.

Comment: The example in the footnote should actually be a class that does not define `n` to be anything at all. Technically `n` in that example is a member (type, but member), in that case the code would have two issues: `n` not being known as a base, and then not being recognized as a type. Also note that an alternative to both `this->n` and `using InnerBase::n;` is type qualifying the use of `n` as in `InnerBase::n`, which in this case it will yield exactly the same effect (it will be different if `n` was a virtual function in `InnerBase` as it would inhibit dynamic dispatch)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Edited, thanks. Good point about how qualifying the name doesn't work for virtual member functions.